# Unity web player is responding late when using with pipelight

Tags: ubuntu, unity-web-player

I am trying to run unity web player in firefox. I came to know about the Pipelight plugin for firefox.

The problem is I am able to install and enable pipelight. While loading any unity application website, the program loads very slow. It responds after 5 minutes for any interaction. I know I am running on old computer, but still I am able to load this application flawlessly in Windows.

*Here is my computer configuration:*

```
Intel core 2 duo E7500 2.9Ghz, 2GB RAM
Asus P5kpl AM EPU
Intel G31 Chipset. 
500GB hard drive. 
Ubuntu 12.04.5 Desktop i386
```

*Steps I did for for installation,*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

I tried to run the unity application website with firefox, it loaded the for few minutes and gave this message

" To run unity web player you need DX 9 based Graphics Card"

I know that my intel chipset is capable of running it, since it is running in windows. I figured out the issue is with graphics drivers.

*Then I ran few command to install intel graphics drivers.*

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
 $ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

After restarting

The Graphics drivers were displaying in Settings-> Details.

Now I decided to run the application again. It was loading and finally worked. But the response time was slow. For selecting every option it took 2 to 3 minutes. The app which I was running normally runs flawlessly in windows but in Ubuntu it was not responding on time and very slow (Almost like frozen).

Can you people tell me a workaround for this issue?
It might be a ubuntu intel chipset driver issue or I might have missed out something. 
Please help. 
I have already posted it here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/649839/unity-web-player-is-responding-late-when-using-with-pipelight